# Violação de Acesso em projeto quando setado Optimization

Tags: delphi

Estou num projeto onde não sei porque acontece uma *violação de acesso* quando tento abrir o programa somente no *modo Release*, no *modo debug* esse erro não aparece.
O erro acontece na chamada da função `DoShow` do `VCL.Forms`.
O erro aparentemente não parece estar no meu código pois o erro acontece após o `FormShow` e antes do `FormActivate`, o que poderia ser?

**update**

Percebi que tal problema somente ocorre quando no meu projeto eu seto o Optimizador para On, qual a relação disso?

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o codigo onde da erro, para ajudar

Comment: @Tmc o problema é que o erro ele aparece como se fosse nos fontes do próprio Delphi. No meu código ele não gera o erro, tanto que quando da exceção e clico em break, ele mostra o código de execução do vcl.forms

Comment: Ok, ta na parte do Código que acredita esta o problema, no caso `Show` coloque ShowMessage('inicio') e ShowMessage('Fim') em blocos de códigos, dessa forma você `"Depura no Release"`

Comment: @JúniorMoreira E acontece isso: Coloquei o ShowMessage('inicio') no final do form.OnShow e o ShowMessage('fim') no começo do código do Form.OnActivate e deu erro entre essas duas msgs